# How, in a plugin, can I check that a User's "Favourite Entries" field contains a specific Entry?

Tags: plugin-development, relations

Users in my project have a Favourite Entries field. In my plugin I want to check whether a specific Entry is present in that field for that user. I'm passing the Entry ID to look for. I am not interested in getting the Entry itself - I just want to check to see if it's already in the Favourite Entries field or not.

I'd hoped that this would work:

```
if( $user->favouriteEntriesField->id($searchingForThisEntryId)->total() === 0 ) {
    ... doesn't contain the Entry yet ...
}
```

But it doesn't work ( Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string )

[edit]

A working solution is to loop through everything:

```
foreach ($user->favouriteEntriesField as $favouriteEntry) {
    MyPlugin::log("ID of loop iterations Favourite Entry: $favouriteEntry->id", LogLevel::Info);

    if($favouriteEntry->id === $searchingForThisEntryId) {
        craft()->userSession->setError(Craft::t('This document is already favourited.'));

        $this->documentFavourited = "yes";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [find()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/ElementCriteriaModel#find-detail) method or better [first()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/ElementCriteriaModel#first-detail) method.

`first()` returns `EntryModel` or `null`.

```
if( $user->favouriteEntriesField->first(['id' => $searchingForThisEntryId]) ) {
    craft()->userSession->setError(Craft::t('This document is already favourited.'));
}
```

Here we take advantage of [baseModel's setAttributes() method](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/BaseModel#setAttributes-detail) that is being used by first() method.

```
/**
 *   @var searchingForThisEntry EntryModel
 */

if( $user->favouriteEntriesField->first($searchingForThisEntry) ) {
    craft()->userSession->setError(Craft::t('This document is already favourited.'));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid looping by getting an array of the IDs of the favourite entries, then check to see if the specific Entry ID is in the array.

```
$favouriteEntryIds = $user->favouriteEntriesField->ids();
if( in_array($searchingForThisEntryId, $favouriteEntryIds) ) {
    ... the Entry has already been favourited ...
}
```